# Smarty template with pagination

Tags: php, smarty

I am starting to learn smarty and I have simple code like this to display all the blog posts on the page:

```
{foreach from=$posts item=post}
<div class="posts">
 <div class="title">
  <a href="{$post->getUrl()}"><h3>{$post->getTitle()}</h3></a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  {$post->getContent()}
  <hr />
</div>
</div>
{/foreach}
```

I am going over array of posts and displaying them on page. But I would like to add pagination. For example, show only 10 posts per page. If there are more than 10 posts, show them on other page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With php, just put the first 10 posts in the $post variable that you send to smarty and add a link to the same page with a page parameter, i.e. posts.php?page=2. Then when page=2 read posts 11 to 20 and so on

Comment: I had something like this in mind! This is with php? `$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 0;
$elementsPerPage = 10;
$elements = array_slice($nodes, $page * $elementsPerPage, $elementsPerPage);

foreach($elements as $node)
{
    echo "Here is the output: ".$node."<br>\n";
}`

Comment: yes, something like that, except that you send $elements to smarty and do the foreach in the template